# Node build issue on TFS

Tags: node.js, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, msdeploy

TFS Builds work on all all projects except the Node for Visual Studio Project.

I get this error:

```
$/IT/my-home.njsproj - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s), View Log File
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (132): Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\my-home.exe" because it was not found.
```

I tried to do this below in the targets file:

```
<Disable_CopyWebApplication Condition="'$(Disable_CopyWebApplication)' == ''">True</Disable_CopyWebApplication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this issue. Add this to your build arguments:
`/p:Disable_CopyWebApplication=True`

[image: Build config]

Comment: Going to take a look tomorrow when I'm back at work  - hopefully this works   thx